# Regex to get names of all SQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a `CREATE TABLE` document and I need to get a listing of all the table names. This is what I have:

```
CREATE TABLE `mturk_reviewqueue` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `catalog_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tv_series_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `added_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `correct_url` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
  `completed_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `completed_by_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `top_url` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `diff_score` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip_checkout` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  `incorrect_original_url` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fix_notes` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_promotional_content` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contains_multiple_titles` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_garbage_series` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `completed_by` (`completed_by_id`),
  KEY `catalog_id` (`catalog_id`),
  KEY `tv_series_id` (`tv_series_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `mturk_reviewqueue_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`completed_by_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `mturk_reviewqueue_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`catalog_id`) REFERENCES `main_catalog` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `mturk_reviewqueue_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`tv_series_id`) REFERENCES `main_tvseriesinstance` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=196089 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Create syntax for TABLE 'mturk_worker'
CREATE TABLE `mturk_worker` (
  `worker_id` varchar(22) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `notes` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
```

...etc...

And this is what I need:

```
mturk_reviewqueue
mturk_worker
etc...
```

So far I have:

```
r'CREATE\sTABLE\s`(.+)`\s\('
```

This is getting me the table name, but I can't seem to get rid of all the junk after the table name but before the next one. What would be the best regex to do this?

Comment: In what environment are you running this regular expression over this input file?

Comment: TextMate (Mac) is the program I'm trying to extract this from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
r'CREATE\sTABLE\s`(.+?)`'
```

This should do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like a command line option. Say your sql file is named "foo":

```
cat foo | grep 'CREATE TABLE' | cut -d\` -f2
```

This should work on MacOS.

Comment: This works, albeit it seems incredibly slow on a large db file.

Answer (score 0):

This should also work (even when there should be more than one blank between words) ...

```
/CREATE\s+TABLE\s+`([^`]+)`/g
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [ack](http://beyondgrep.com) you can do this:

```
ack 'CREATE TABLE `(.+)`' --output='$1'
```